# How to use toFixed(2) in ng-bind angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using ng-bind to bind the value of price

```
 <td><span ng-bind="'$' o.Price"></span></td>
```

but it is taking value like this **281.96000000000004**
so how can I restrict this value in view so it takes only two digits after decimal.
like **281.96.**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the `number` filter

```
 <td><span ng-bind="'$' + (o.Price | number : 2)"></span></td>
```

Comment: @Gaurav_0093 nice. make sure to check as answer if this helped :D

Answer (score 2):

You can use the currency filter (if it's a price in dollars):

`<td><span>{{ o.Price | currency }}</span></td>`

Answer (score 1):

you can use angular filter  `| number : fractionSize`
 for two decimal places fractionSize use:

```
  <td><span ng-bind="'$' o.Price| number : 2"></span></td>
```